# Scan a single column in SQL Server for a data entry using python

Tags: python, sql-server

Example of a column:

[image: Single column table]

This is what I have tried. I only want to search based on a single column in the table. Lets says the table name is `Employees`. The `input` parameter is entered by the user in console.

```
exists = cursor.execute("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Employees WHERE ID = ?", (str(input),))
print(exists)
if exists is None:
    return False
else:
    return True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
insert_query = '''SELECT TOP 1 * FROM EmployeeTable WHERE ID = (?);''' # '?' is a placeholder
cursor.execute(insert_query, str(input))
```